# Reading GPIO status only works outside of PHP if statement?

Tags: gpio, php

I can read a GPIO pin's status as such:

```
<?php
     exec ( "gpio read 7", $status );
     print_r ( $status );
?>
```

this works fine. But I want to read the status from within a php if statement, eg:

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['trigger']) && $_GET['trigger'] == 1) {
         exec ( "gpio read 7", $status );
         print_r ( $status );
         exec ( "gpio write 7 1" );
}
?>
```

Though `exec ('gpio write 7 1');` works, the read and print does not.

Would anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: how do you know the write works and the read and print don't?

Comment: @SteveRobillard the LED I have attached to that GPIO is triggered. The read probably works but is still not being printed to the the screen like it does normally.

Comment: you cannot read from an OUT pin, you should use different pin and configure pin you would like to read as input using `gpio mode <pin> in`

Comment: @mpromonet I'm going to disagree with that -- you *can* check the value of an out pin.

Comment: @goldilocks : mea maxima culpa. I did not checked, and you're right `gpio read <pin>` works on an out pin.

Answer (score 1):

exec adds the returned value to the end of the array $status.
So first time, required value is in $status(0).
Next time, old value is still in $status(0), but new value is in $status(1), etc for further loops.
Fix is to use unset($status) each time round the loop so that exec always adds new value in $status(0).

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I came up with when I had this same problem.  This post helped me figure out what the issue was.

```
function closevalve ($valve) {
        $status[0] = 2;
        while ($status[0] != 1) {
            system ( "gpio write ".$valve." 1" );
            exec ( "gpio read ".$valve, $statusa );
            $status[0] = $statusa[0];
        };
        unset($status);
        unset($statusa);
        echo date("h:i:s A")." - ".whichpin($valve)." Off<br>";
        ob_flush();flush();
        sleep(5);
    };
```